# Running an xml file error Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, xml

I have here a .xml file. When I run it to my browser, I have an error that says "**error on line 37 at column 3: Extra content at the end of the document**", Is my code the error, what part, or is it because its a .xml file? I tried to make it .php it works but I need a .xml file?

Here is my full code.

```
<?php
require("config.php");
$connection=mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword);
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $databaseName);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM markers";
$res = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('markers');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $xml->startElement("marker");

  $xml->writeAttribute('id', $row['id']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('name', $row['name']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('address', $row['address']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('contact_number', $row['contact_number']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('contact_number1', $row['contact_number1']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('contact_number2', $row['contact_number2']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('lng', $row['lng']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('lat', $row['lat']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('image', $row['image']);

  $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();

header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml->flush();
?>
```

Comment: save file, open in text editor, what's the extra content?

Comment: Save it as xml you mean?@smith

Comment: The XML parser is complaining that there are literally extra characters after the closing XML element eg `<xml></xml>fooie` as an XML document would generate this parser error.

Comment: save as anything.

Comment: How to fix that kind of thing? @Scuzzy

Comment: I save it as xml, then how can i see the extra content?

Comment: "open in text editor"

Comment: Do you just want to have a chatbox instead? So that i can show you @smith

Comment: @gwapo unless you show us a sample of what kind of data is being added to the end of the XML document, no one here can help you.

Comment: Can I suggest removing `$xml->flush();` or change it to `$xml->endDocument();` and seeing what happens? You're already streaming to `php://output`

Comment: I just simply show an xml from the database